# reading data from firebase firestore collection at stream builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I got trouble with firebase fireStore.
There is a stream builder reading data from items collection.
Inside items collection there is some fields and another collections.
I haven't any problem with fields, the problem is with collection.
how to access those collections inside stream builder?

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: CallApi().finalReference(reference: widget.finalReference),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('snapshot Error:${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var snapData = snapshot.data!.docs;
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(snapData.length);
            }
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListItem(
                        mTitle: snapData[index].get('title') ?? '',
                        mSubTitle: snapData[index].get('address') ?? 'empty',
                        mPrice: snapData[index].get('price') ?? '',
                        mImageUrl: snapData[index].get('gallery')[0],
                        mOnTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                                adsTitle: snapData[index].get('title'),
                                adsSubTitle: snapData[index].get('subTitle'),
                                gallery: snapData[index].get('gallery'),
                                specFTitle: snapData[index].get('gallery'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
```

**here is firebase**

[image: sssd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading data from Firestore is a shallow operation. When you read a document, its subcollection are **not** automatically read.

So if you want to get the data from the subcollections of the current document, you will have to start a new read operation for that. If you want to show that data in the UI, you can use a new, nested `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder` for that.

Comment: Useing nested StreamBuilder dosn't effect on apps' speed?

Comment: The nested `StreamBuilder`s don't really make a difference, but the extra reads might of course. With your current data structure there's not much different you can do though. If the performance is impact, consider merging information you need for the current screen into fewer documents - maybe even all in the parent document.